# Delete line if string between the 4th and 5th delimiter is empty

Tags: sed, line

```
"text";"text";"text";"text";;"text";"text"
```

If after the 4th delimiter the next one is following the line should be deleted.

Actually i'm doing that by using sed

```
sed -n '/;;/!p' input.txt
```

Is this a reliable solution?

Thanks for help.

Comment: NO because any other "empty" field will catch the fire also or you could assume that no other field could be empty. Empty is not `""`.

Comment: When dealing with columns, awk should initially be the first command to jump into your head ;)

Answer (score 1):

Securing a bit potential escaped double quote and internal ";" (thanks @SLePort for remark)

```
sed -e 'h;s/\\"//g' -e ':c' -e 's/^\(\("[^"]*";\)*"[^"]*\);/\1/;t c' -e '/^\([^;]*;\)\{4\};/d;h'
```

Comment: works great. so if a want to check if after the last ; some text is following, i only need to replace 4 by 6?

Comment: yes or start from other side using `;$` that is certainly faster in this case

Comment: It will fail if a quoted string before fourth field contain `;`. eg: `"text";"text;text";"text";"text";;"text";"text"`

Answer (score 0):

To remove lines containing `;` after fourth delimiter:

```
sed '/^\("*[^"]*"*;\)\{4\};/d' input.txt
```

Comment: not secure due to `"this a ;; double; or\" single quote";"..."` that could occur in string

Comment: Fine and lot better than mine if there is is no `\"` inside, and it could be assumed by OP

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r '/^([^;]+;){4}\s*;/d' input.txt
awk -F';' '$5' input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/^("(\\.|[^"])*";){4};/d' file
```

If the fourth grouping of double quotes followed by semi colon, where the characters within the grouping are either a pair of a quote and any other character or not a double quote, is followed by a further semi colon, then delete the line.

A more efficient regexp would be:

```
sed -r '/^("[^"\\]*(\\.[^"\\]*)*";){4};/d' file
```

This uses the pattern ***normal****(***abnormal*** ***normal****)*